# Is it possible to combine two types to create another TypeLiteral?

Tags: java, generics, types, guice, thrift

Given this method signature, is it possible to implement it? If so, how?

```
TypeLiteral<MyClass<T, R>> combineTypes(Class<T> typeOne, Class<R> typeTwo) {
  // Awesome implementation here
}
```

---

**Background**

I have an interface, `ApiHandler<TReq, TRes>` which I am trying to create in a factory, with Guice, given type `TReq`. I can also pass in the type `TRes` if necessary. Unfortunately, the `TReq` and `TRes` have no meaningful parent classes or interfaces for reasons beyond my control (they are generated from Apache Thrift).

Comment: Do you have access to Guava's `TypeToken`? You basically need to build a new `ParameterizedType` object. Alternatively, you need to change your API so that your factory's *caller* constructs the `TypeLiteral` and passes it in.

Comment: Yes, I have access to Guava. Could you elaborate more on your suggestion with `ParameterizedType` object? Also, re: your second suggestion, you mean the caller passes in a `TypeLiteral<MyClass<T, R>>`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're computing it based on runtime arguments, it's no longer a *literal*: It's just a Type.

Though you could use Guava's equivalent framework of TypeToken and its utilities, there's a Type utility class built into Guice: [com.google.inject.util.Types](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/util/Types.html). Use [`newParameterizedType(Type rawType, Type... typeArguments)`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/util/Types.html#newParameterizedType-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.reflect.Type...-) to create the Type you want, noting that ParameterizedType and Class both implement Type.

```
static ParameterizedType combineTypes(Class<?> typeOne, Class<?> typeTwo) {
  return Types.newParameterizedType(MyClass.class, typeOne, typeTwo);
}
```

Unfortunately, `AbstractModule.bind` and `LinkedBindingBuilder.to` don't offer overloads for Type; just Class, TypeLiteral, and Key. Luckily, you can generate a Key reflectively using a Type, using [`Key.get(Type)`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Key.html#get-java.lang.reflect.Type-):

```
bind(Key.get(combineTypes(Foo.class, Bar.class))).to(MyClassFooBar.class);
```

Note, in this, that ParameterizedType is not itself a parameterized type. This defeats some of the clever generics-based protection that Guice's `bind` EDSL offers. To get the above to work, you may need to `@SuppressWarnings`, return the raw type `Key`, or consider having `combineTypes` return a `Key<MyClass<T, R>>` (which would require a cast from `Key.get(Type)`'s return value `Key<?>`). If you really must use a TypeLiteral, you can produce a TypeLiteral through [Key.getTypeLiteral](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Key.html#getTypeLiteral--), but that would also require a cast from `TypeLiteral<?>`—and would not be a "type literal" by any meaningful definition.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand (well, at least more than yesterday) these topics!

Answer (score 1):

`TypeLiteral` has two constructors; the normal one when used as intended `TypeLiteral<MyClass<Foo, Bar>>() {}`, and the unsafe one which is not generic and is created directly: `new TypeLiteral(type)`. Looking at the code for Guice's TypeLiteral [here](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/core/src/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.java), we see the regular constructor uses `parameterized.getActualTypeArguments()[0]` for this parameter, where `parameterized` is a `ParameterizedType`. To make something that matches `MyClass<R, T>`, this would be another `ParameterizedType`, but with two parameters, not one, and each parameter would be a plain class. You can now create an implementation of the `ParameterizedType` interface that fulfills the contract needed, construct a `TypeLiteral`, and cast it to the correct return value (it won't have the correct generic type, you'll have to do an unsafe cast).

It looks like this:

```
TypeLiteral<MyClass<T, R>> combineTypes(Class<T> typeOne, Class<R> typeTwo) {
    return new TypeLiteral(new ParameterizedType() {
        @RecentlyNonNull
        Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
            return new Type[] {typeOne, typeTwo};
        }

        @RecentlyNonNull
        Type getRawType() {
            return MyClass.class;
        }

        Type getOwnerType() {
            // this is only needed for nested classes, eg. if this was Foo.Myclass this would return Foo.class.
            return null;
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Will try it out today and report back!

Comment: Bad news, the unsafe constructor is private to the package and I cannot invoke it. Though, your second suggestion up above seems more promising?

Unless you have any other ideas to get it working it the way of the first suggestion, do you mind editing your answer to the second suggestion and I'll mark it as accepted?

Comment: It actually looks like Jeff Bowman's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53181569/1685098) provides a better solution; you should use that instead.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't use Guice or Thrift before, hope this can help.

Definition of MyClass: `public class MyClass<T, R> {}`

Implement the method by adding type parameter:

```
public static <T, R> TypeLiteral<MyClass<T, R>> combineTypes(Class<T> typeOne, Class<R> typeTwo) {
    return new TypeLiteral<MyClass<T, R>>() {};
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TypeLiteral<MyClass<Integer, String>> myClassTypeLiteral = TypeTest.combineTypes(Integer.class, String.class);
}
```

Or simply:

```
public static <T, R> TypeLiteral<MyClass<T, R>> combineTypes() {
    return new TypeLiteral<MyClass<T, R>>() {};
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TypeLiteral<MyClass<Integer, String>> myClassTypeLiteral = TypeTest.<Integer, String>combineTypes();
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will work. The TypeLiteral won't capture runtime types: it will just close over the type variables, which won't help here.